# connect to mqtt broker after disconnecting from another broker using nodejs lib

Tags: node.js, mqtt

The scenario that i want to implement is , first my service will connect to a mqtt broker , when i receive a message from a will topic , i want to disconnect it from the broker my mqtt client was connected and connect to some other broker.is it possible to do this using nodejs library??

```js
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://192.168.100.3')

client.on('connect', function () {
  console.log("connected to broker")
  client.subscribe('mqtt_node_subscribe')
  client.publish('mqtt_node_publish', 'Hello mqtt')
})
client.on('close',function(){
  console.log("connection closed")
})
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  // message is Buffer 
  console.log("message arrived")
  
    client.end()
    client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://192.168.100.14')
  }})
```

I was able to disconnect from the current broker , but unable to connect to the other one, after disconnection Console messages are:

```
connected to broker
message arrived
connection closed
```

Comment: Try replacing the second `connect()` inside `'close'` event. Also, it is good to monitor `error` event if not.

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing the client object so you need to recreate all the event handlers

e.g.

```
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  // message is Buffer 
  console.log("message arrived")

  client.end()

  client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://192.168.100.14');
  client.on('connect', function () {
  ...
   });
   client.on('close',function(){
   ...
   })
}})
```

Comment: still, it is not connected to the other broker

Comment: should i have to clear client reference variable before connecting to another mqtt server

Comment: @Lisa Edited my answer after thinking about it

Comment: in that case, i have to create all event listeners in 'on message' callback .is there any other way i can do this dynamically

Comment: without knowing what you are actually trying to achieve it's hard to say, but you will need to set the callbacks after each connection. You can declare them as named functions and just pass in the names rather than anonymous functions.